# Need to see if a set of dates put together are bigger or equal than a fixed range in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores dates, the schema is:

```
  TENANT | START DATE | END DATE  | LOFT
```

And imagine the following range : **2015-07-01 to 2015-08-01**

If in that table i had the following rows

```
   Lisa  | 2015-06-29 | 2015-07-15 | 1
   George| 2015-07-15 | 2015-08-01 | 1
   Anna  | 2015-07-01 | 2015-08-10 | 2
   Luke  | 2015-05-01 | 2015-07-15 | 3
   Hailey| 2015-07-17 | 2015-08-01 | 3
```

I want to see if a LOFT is on a rental period during a fixed-range. Loft 3 is discarted cause is stays unihabited during 2 days from 07-15 to 07-17.
I would need to return **both loft 1 and 2**. Any ideas of how to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the logic you want to use to select those rows.

Comment: I want to see if a LOFT is on a rental period during a fixed-range. Loft 3 is    discarted cause is stays unihabited during 2 days. From 07-15 till 07-17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to expand all dates in the range.  This is a brute force approach:

```
with cte as (
      select cast('2015-07-01' as date) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from cte
      where dateadd(day, 1, dte) <= cast('2015-08-01' as date)
)
select loft
from t join
     cte
     on cte.dte between t.startdate and t.enddate
group by loft
having count(distinct cte.dte) = (select count(*) from cte);
```

Note:  this uses a recursive subquery to get the days in the range.  It could also use a calendar table or number table.

Comment: Thanks , I will test it right away, thanks for the feedback

Comment: It works perfectly, can you explain it more or less of how it works cause I didnt quite understand it ? Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @LiveByIt . . . The CTE expands to all the dates in the range.  The `having` clause in conjunction with the join guarantee that no dates are missing.